# Check if one item in a list is in a list of lists

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list of lists, e.g:

```
my_list = [['ab', 'bc'], ['cd', 'de'], ['ef', 'fg'], ['gh', 'hi']]
```

I then have a list of no-go words, e.g:

```
no_go_list = ['ab', 'fg']
```

What I would like to do is to get a list, where it checks if at least one of the items in the `no_go_list` is in one of the lists in `my_list`, so the result should just be:

```
final_list = [['cd', 'de'], ['gh', 'hi']]
```

I was thinking about doing it like this:

```
final_list = [l for l in my_list if not no_go_list in l]
```

But this checks if both of the `no_go_list` items present. So I am guessing this needs some modification, I just can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: *"obviously checks if both of the no_go_list items present"* - That's not obvious to me...

Comment: I see you removed the word "obviously". That was not the issue. The issue was and is that your statement is *wrong*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check whether any item in `no_go_list` is in the element.  Thus, the "obvious" way is to use the `any` function.

```
final_list = [l for l in my_list 
                if not any(word in l for word in no_go_list)]
```

Your posted code does *not* check for both of the items being present: it checks to see whether that *list* value is present.  You would need something like

```
my_list = [[['ab', 'fg'], 'bc'], ['cd', 'de'], 
            ['ef', ['ab', 'fg']], ['gh', 'hi']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a set...

```
>>> list(filter(set(no_go_list).isdisjoint, my_list))
[['cd', 'de'], ['gh', 'hi']]
```